# findByIdAndUpdate updating wrong sub-objects when using $set

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

To clarify, I'm trying to build a feature to let my users manage the notifications and emails they receive.

In order to do that, I decided to implement an object with several objects within itself.

Everything seems to make sense in my head but I'm here because I found a problem and I can not solve it by myself.

**Here is the problem:**

I have two endpoints and two function, each endpoint calls their respective function. Everytime I make a call to any of the two endpoints, said call updates not only the data on its endpoint but in the other endpoint as well, do I explain myself?

Let's put it this way, this is endpoint A `{{URL}}/api/v1/auth/updateemailnotifications` and this ednpoint B `{{URL}}/api/v1/auth/updatenotifications`. No matter which one is called, it updates the other's endpoint data as well.

ENDPOINT A:

```
  const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    {
      _id: req.user._id
    },
    {
      $set: {
        settings: {
          notifications: {
            comments: {
              fromBlogNotification: req.body.fromBlogNotification,
              fromPostNotification: req.body.fromPostNotification,
              fromVideoNotification: req.body.fromVideoNotification,
              fromMediaNotification: req.body.fromMediaNotification,
              fromProducerNotification: req.body.fromProducerNotification,
              fromJobNotification: req.body.fromJobNotification,
              fromCommentNotification: req.body.fromCommentNotification
            },
            news: {
              fromBlogNewsNotification: req.body.fromBlogNewsNotification,
              fromProducerNewsNotification:
                req.body.fromProducerNewsNotification,
              fromUserNewsNotification: req.body.fromUserNewsNotification
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      new: true,
      runValidators: true,
      // setDefaultsOnInsert: true
    }
  );
```

ENDPOINT B:

```
  const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    {
      _id: req.user._id
    },
    {
      $set: {
        settings: {
          emails: {
            comments: {
              fromBlogComments: req.body.fromBlogComments,
              fromPostComments: req.body.fromPostComments,
              fromVideoComments: req.body.fromVideoComments,
              fromMediaComments: req.body.fromMediaComments,
              fromProducerComments: req.body.fromProducerComments,
              fromJobComments: req.body.fromJobComments,
              fromCommentComments: req.body.fromCommentComments
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      new: true,
      runValidators: true,
      // setDefaultsOnInsert: true
    }
  );
```

Hopefully you guys can help me solve this, thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are replacing the whole `settings` with the new value. To update specific field in `settings`, you need to use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#embedded-documents):

```
const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  { _id: req.user._id },
  {
    $set: {
      'settings.notifications': {
      ...
      }
    }
  },...
```

Comment: thank you, I can not believe I did not think of that